# Android анимация

Tags: android, android-animation

Есть надпись в `TextView` и мне нужно чтобы она при нажатии смещалась в право по горизонтали на допустим 10dp и после окончания она оставалась на том же месте куда она сместилась.

Я вот как то так написал но оно вообще не работает, оно почему-то начинает смещаться в право с начала Activty а не с того места где стояло `TextView`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="50"
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Советую сначала разобраться, что делает каждый тег, прежде чем узнавать, почему это работает не так, как вы думали. Например, [здесь](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/347918/)

Comment: android:fillAfter="true" уберите fromXDelta fromYDelta и вперед читать документацию